# Find a TCP network debugger like fiddler but with other ports beside 80

Tags: tcp, network-protocols

I have used [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture traffic through http 80 port.

But I am looking for some free tool which can capture TCP traffic on any other ports.

For example, I have abc.exe running on my machine. I open the tool, targeting abc.exe process, and I can see what package abc.exe is sending to what address.

Is there any good tool for this?

Comment: Just to be clear here, Fiddler cares not one wit about port. But it supports only the HTTP/HTTPS and FTP protocols.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), I think it's the best.

Comment: One point to keep in mind is that packet sniffers like WireShark and Microsoft Network Monitor typically cannot show you plaintext traffic if it was encrypted (e.g. HTTPS).

Comment: Err - @EricLaw Technically they can to some extent if you configure the encryption keys from options that is if you know the keys. I have personally done this for IPsec. But i don't see why this does not apply to HTTPS

Comment: Yeah just verified this for SSL too. Wireshark->Edit->Preferences->Protocols->SSL. Here you would see option to enter Shared key or RSA key file. It is pretty much similar for IPsec though the encrypted protocol name is ESP